# asynchbeans WorkManager & CommonJ Scheduling integration

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7, workmanagers

I need to develop a scheduler which will run a task once a day, and will run in Websphere. i have been looking at the WorkManager API and I can't find anything regarding how the work can be scheduled. However, after doing some other search I have found that commonj can be used with the WorkManager - however I cant find any good example on how this can be done.

Any pointers on this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use EJB 3 TimerService for this purpose.

The problem with asyncbeans is that they are not persistent.

EJB3 Timers are persistent (file store by default) and can be configured to use a custom WebSphere scheduler if you need something special.

Usually the defaults are enough.

Check this tutorial: [Using the Timer Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)